# Get All Sales Order from Quick Book via QuickBook WebConnector using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap, quickbooks

I am using QuicBook Premier Edition UK , I have a company file open inside QuickBook. Build a sample WebService provided in samples and host in IIS. Added that application in WebConnector by using qwc file in samples.
I understood the callback methods required by WebConnector in soap service.

• authenticate

• clientVersion

• closeConnection

• connectionError

• getLastError

• receiveResponseXML

• sendRequestXML

I have tested web service by using WebConnector by using Update Selected button and it gives response 'OK' . But I am still confused how to get started with soap service , samples include 3 Xml request
CustomerQuery, 
InvoiceQuery and 
BillQuery .
How I test these request and see the response by using service . Can anyone explain the steps required to get me started with my own request of Get all Sales Order.
Thanks

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Here is the Last Output.
Version:
2.0.0.1

Message:
OK

Description:
Via closeConnection(): CloseConnection called to application.
Response received from application = OK

Comment: If you continue to have trouble implementing after reading the answer(s) below, please POST YOUR CODE so that we can help you with the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

After calling `authenticate(...)`, the Web Connector will call the `sendRequestXML(...)` method.

The `sendRequestXML(...)` method is essentially the Web Connector's way of saying "Hey, what do you want me to do?"

You should respond with a qbXML request telling QuickBooks/the Web Connector to do something. For example, if you are trying to get sales orders from QuickBooks, you could respond with a `SalesOrderQuery` qbXML request, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderQueryRq requestID="2">

        </SalesOrderQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The Web Connector will then send that request to QuickBooks, it will be processed, and the Web Connector will then call your `receiveResponseXML(...)` method.

The `receiveResponseXML(...)` method is essentially the Web Connector's way of saying "Hey, you told me to do something, I did it, and here's all of the data I got back: ... (big blob of XML from QuickBooks here)".

**TLDR:**

Return a qbXML request from the `sendRequestXML` method. A qbXML response will be sent to you in the `receiveResponseXML` method.

**More notes:**

- Bigger explanation of the Web Connector here: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview
- Lots of qbXML examples here: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests
- Hundreds of pages of documentation in the QuickBooks SDK: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads